# ORACLE Query Count Slow

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to query my Oracle script on Toad but got slow response, about 4-8 seconds.

The script query is about count, below is mine:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
AS TOTALS 
FROM(SELECT S.BADGEID_FK, S.SHIFT, S.STATUS, E.BADGEID, E.FIRSTNAME, E.LASTNAME 
     FROM WA_SEW_TBL_EMP_INFO S, WA_GA_TBL_EMPLOYEES E 
     WHERE S.BADGEID_FK = E.BADGEID AND S.STATUS = 'Attend' AND S.SHIFT = 'Morning' 
       AND S.BADGEID_FK NOT IN(SELECT EMPID 
                               FROM WA_SEW_TBL_RESULTS 
                               WHERE TO_CHAR(SYSTEM_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = '2017-08-30' 
                                 AND TO_CHAR(SYSTEM_DATE, 'HH24:MI') >= '07:00' 
                                 AND TO_CHAR(SYSTEM_DATE, 'HH24:MI') <= '19:29'))
```

I tried to add indexing to some column, but there is no effect.

Is there any way to do that query? or any trick?

Comment: Do you really mean <= 19:29 or do you mean < 19:30?

Comment: @xQbert - as written, they are equivalent: the OP is essentially truncating the seconds portion.

Comment: @all Thanks for the answering. I got the result now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part:

```
WHERE TO_CHAR(SYSTEM_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = '2017-08-30' 
                                 AND TO_CHAR(SYSTEM_DATE, 'HH24:MI') >= '07:00' 
                                 AND TO_CHAR(SYSTEM_DATE, 'HH24:MI') <= '19:29'
```

Would be better rewritten as:

```
WHERE SYSTEM_DATE between to_date ('2017-08-30 07:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
                      and to_date ('2017-08-30 19:29:59', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

That will allow any index on `SYSTEM_DATE` to be used.

Comment: This is not quite equivalent to the original query... the original version allowed the time to be 19:29:55, since it just extracted hour and minute. In date comparisons, that should be changed to < 19:30.

Comment: (...which observation, obviously, flew right over the OP's head...)

Comment: @mathguy Thanks I've amended my answer to return same results as OP's query.

Answer (score 2):

One obvious suspect is your date manipulation in the `IN` list. You should never, ever use functions around dates - that kills any ability of Oracle to use an index on the date column.

Instead:

```
where system_date >= to_date('2017-08-30 07:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi')
  and system_date <  to_date('2017-08-30 19:30', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi')
```

(the second inequality is strict, if you want to **ex**clude 7:30pm sharp).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to eliminate most of the subqueries but I'm not sure it will result in the performance gain w/o knowledge of table size and indexes.  Posting the execution plan would help us understand where your bottleneck is.

```
SELECT count(*) as Totals
FROM WA_SEW_TBL_EMP_INFO S
INNER JOIN WA_GA_TBL_EMPLOYEES E 
   ON S.BADGEID_FK = E.BADGEID 
LEFT JOIN WA_SEW_TBL_RESULTS R
   ON S.BADGEID_FK =R.EMPID
   -- Others already addressed what needs to happen here.
  AND TO_CHAR(R.SYSTEM_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = '2017-08-30' 
  AND TO_CHAR(R.SYSTEM_DATE,'HH24:MI') >= '07:00' 
  AND TO_CHAR(R.SYSTEM_DATE,'HH24:MI') <= '19:29'
WHERE S.STATUS = 'Attend' 
  AND S.SHIFT = 'Morning' 
  AND R.EmpID is null
```